# Change url pages magento languages

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, language

I have two pages in my store one in spanish and other in english.

I have the shortcode put, but when i changed between pages the URLs changes like this:
 http://tienda.mabaonline.com/en/?___from_store=es

I want this http://tienda.mabaonline.com/en
How I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly go to admin panel `System -> Configuration` Under `Configuration -> Web -> Url` options and change `Add Store Code to Urls` to ‘Yes’.

Then change template file app/design/frontend//default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

search for this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>
```

and change it to this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work :S

Comment: you did it the right way?

Comment: I'll did it like this:  Type:custom store:English ID path: `en/?____from_store=es`  Request Path:  `en/?____from_store=es`Target Path: `http://tienda.mabaonline.com/en`

Comment: no use the names of each home page not that. i updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: I don't have to write  http://tienda.mabaonline.com/en, just `/en` in the Target Path ?

Comment: the english home page what's the identifier of it?

Comment: tienda.mabaonline.com/en so the Id is /en

Comment: try that but now that i am thinking of it it wont make any difference

Comment: No it doesn't work :S

Comment: i added another answer check it out.

Comment: Okay I'm gonna try