# Optimise URL when changing Store and language switcher to maintain SEO standards

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, store-view, language

I want to optimize the store view URL to maintain the SEO standards when switching the language view in Magento1.9 front end.

Example

```
localhost/magento/?___store=french&___from_store=german
```

To

```
localhost/magento/(some german string) like

localhost/magento/de_DE/
```

If Spanish

```
localhost/magento/(some spanish string)
```

I have tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69320/change-url-pages-magento-languages) but no luck.

Any help much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **prefix** all URLs with a string like `de_DE`, set that string as the store code (instead of `german`) and use the "Add Store Code To URL" configuration in the answer you linked. This way, the `___store` and `___from_store` parameters are not necessary anymore and Magento omits them.

> More info: [M1: Remove "?___store=default" from the URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127358/m1-remove-store-default-from-the-url/127363#127363)

If you want to use this approach, you should ask your question more specifically. By just saying "no luck" nobody can help you because we don't know what you tried and what was the problem.

---

But if you only want to change the URL that is used to switch stores and not **all** URLs, it is going to be complicated.

As long as you're okay with the language switcher always linking to the homepage you could add a `RewriteRule` to your `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^de_DE$ /?___store=german
RewriteRule ^fr_FR$ /?___store=french
```

Then change the switcher template to use these URLs.

For the home page, `___from_store` is not necessary (for an explanation see again the answer linked above)

Comment: @ fschmengler I have modified the question, thanks for the answer and suggestions. I will try this approach.